# Can't wrap directives angular 1.4.1

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, directive

I'm trying to wrap form creation in order to put some logic before running some other directives, like ui.mask and ui.bootstrap. However I haven't been able to perform these other directives. HTML got transformed, but not linked.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in headers.fields | filter: {editable: true}">
      <label for="{{field.name}}" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input ng-show="field.autocomplete === false"
               type="text"
               fw-input

               id="{{field.name}}"
               ng-model="data[field.name]" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
```

Here is how my directive looks like:

```
fwInput.$inject = ['viaCEP', '$timeout', '$compile'];
  function fwInput (viaCEP, $timeout, $compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  //terminal: true,
  // replace: true,
  //priority: 1,
  //scope: true,
  //transclude: true,
  //require: 'ngModel',
  link: {
     pre: function preLink(scope, $el, attrs, controller) {
       if (scope.field.customOptions.cep != undefined) {
         // console.log(scope);

         $el.blur(function() {
           var $scope = angular.element(this).scope();
           viaCEP.get(this.value).then(function(response){
             var map = $scope.field.customOptions.cep;

             $scope.$parent.detail_data[map.address] = response.logradouro;
             $scope.$parent.detail_data[map.district] = response.bairro;
             $scope.$parent.detail_data[map.city] = response.localidade;
             $scope.$parent.detail_data[map.state] = response.uf;
           });
         });
       }
       else if (scope.field.customOptions.cpf != undefined) {
         attrs.$set('ui-mask', "999.999.999-99");
         attrs.$set('ng-cpf')

         // $compile($el)(scope);

         // $compile($el)(scope);
         // ng-cpf ui-mask="999.999.999-99"
       }
       else if (scope.field.type == 'date') {
         attrs.$set('my-datepicker');

       }

       console.log('link pre');
     },
     post: function postLink(scope, $el, attrs, controller) {
     }
  }
}
  }
```

I have already tried some alternatives, with compile, priority, terminal. When I use compile, if I $compile($el)(scope) it gets on infinity loop, if I use priority, somewhy ng-model do not get bind.

I also tried to achieve it with ng-attr-*, but I got into trouble as well.

Is it possible to be achieved? If not, is there a way to bind it directly, like I would with jQuery?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I'm trying to use just one attribute directive to decide when add attributes from other directives, such ui-mask